# Multiple Bash traps for the same signal

Tags: bash, bash-trap

When I use the `trap` command in Bash, the previous `trap` for the given signal is replaced.

Is there a way of making more than one `trap` fire for the same signal?

Comment: I ran into a similar issue and came up with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16115145/1449569)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

**Edit:**

It appears that I misread the question. The answer is simple:

```
handler1 () { do_something; }
handler2 () { do_something_else; }
handler3 () { handler1; handler2; }

trap handler3 SIGNAL1 SIGNAL2 ...
```

---

Original:

Just list multiple signals at the end of the command:

```
trap function-name SIGNAL1 SIGNAL2 SIGNAL3 ...
```

You can find the function associated with a particular signal using `trap -p`:

```
trap -p SIGINT
```

Note that it lists each signal separately even if they're handled by the same function.

You can add an additional signal given a known one by doing this:

```
eval "$(trap -p SIGUSR1) SIGUSR2"
```

This works even if there are other additional signals being processed by the same function. In other words, let's say a function was already handling three signals - you could add two more just by referring to one existing one and appending two more (where only one is shown above just inside the closing quotes).

If you're using Bash >= 3.2, you can do something like this to extract the function given a signal. Note that it's not completely robust because other single quotes could appear.

```
[[ $(trap -p SIGUSR1) =~ trap\ --\ \'([^\047]*)\'.* ]]
function_name=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
```

Then you could rebuild your trap command from scratch if you needed to using the function name, etc.

Comment: He asked for multiple traps for the same signal, not the same trap for multiple signals.

Comment: @Darron: Sorry, I misread the question. The answer to the **actual** question is much simpler and I've added it at the top.

Comment: you are still only firing one trap - that the trap in question invokes multiple functions and achieves the effect is more or less indisputable.  The only reason to think there might be any grounds for dispute is that if handler1 is installed first, and it is designed to exit, then handler2 won't be fired.  But there is still just one action fired off.  (You've always been able to have an arbitrarily complex sequence of operations in the triggered action.)

Comment: @Jonathan: handler3 can run handler1 and 2 in subshells so that it can be sure that both handlers are run and do its own exit (or run all but the last in subshells and let the last do it). Also, handler3 can set a trap on EXIT and make sure that both sub-handlers have been run.

Comment: OK - we're concluding that the question is asking for two different things.  You're assuming that the question is asking "can you do arbitrarily complex operations in a trap handler", to which the answer is, of course, Yes - you can write any shell script commands in the trap handler.  I'm assuming the question is "can I have two separate traps both active: '`trap "xyz" 2`' and '`trap "pqr" 2`' simultaneously, to which the answer is (as I stated) No.  Given the difference in interpretation of the question, there can be no surprise at the difference in the answer.

Comment: Isn't there a missing `*` wildcard from the regex? I presume we want to collect all the chars between the opening and closing single quotes, i.e. `[^\047]*` in our group?

Comment: @DNA: Fixed. Thanks.

Comment: I think Richard Hansen's answer is a better fit, 1) Fetch the existing trap code using trap -p 2) Add your command, separated by a semicolon or newline 3) Set the trap to the result of #2. It also has more votes, and I feel like if you are asking this, it's because you aren't necessarily in control of all the traps?

Comment: This solution much simpler to me. You can place trap right after each handler declaration, just make sure every handler content call the previous handler except the first one of course. You can place any code between any handler and any failed code will call the last trap-ed handler.

Answer (score 87):

Technically you can't set multiple traps for the same signal, but you can add to an existing trap:

1. Fetch the existing trap code using `trap -p`
2. Add your command, separated by a semicolon or newline
3. Set the trap to the result of #2

Here is a bash function that does the above:

```
# note: printf is used instead of echo to avoid backslash
# processing and to properly handle values that begin with a '-'.

log() { printf '%s\n' "$*"; }
error() { log "ERROR: $*" >&2; }
fatal() { error "$@"; exit 1; }

# appends a command to a trap
#
# - 1st arg:  code to add
# - remaining args:  names of traps to modify
#
trap_add() {
    trap_add_cmd=$1; shift || fatal "${FUNCNAME} usage error"
    for trap_add_name in "$@"; do
        trap -- "$(
            # helper fn to get existing trap command from output
            # of trap -p
            extract_trap_cmd() { printf '%s\n' "$3"; }
            # print existing trap command with newline
            eval "extract_trap_cmd $(trap -p "${trap_add_name}")"
            # print the new trap command
            printf '%s\n' "${trap_add_cmd}"
        )" "${trap_add_name}" \
            || fatal "unable to add to trap ${trap_add_name}"
    done
}
# set the trace attribute for the above function.  this is
# required to modify DEBUG or RETURN traps because functions don't
# inherit them unless the trace attribute is set
declare -f -t trap_add
```

Example usage:

```
trap_add 'echo "in trap DEBUG"' DEBUG
```

Comment: Works nicely (as long as trap isn't empty initially)

Comment: What about: trap -p "EXIT" | cut -d " " -f 3 | tr -d "'" instead of extract_trap_cmd ?

Comment: @jehon doesn't work if original trap is multiple lines

Answer (score 13):

## No

About the best you could do is run multiple commands from a single `trap` for a given signal, but you cannot have multiple concurrent traps for a single signal.  For example:

```
$ trap "rm -f /tmp/xyz; exit 1" 2
$ trap
trap -- 'rm -f /tmp/xyz; exit 1' INT
$ trap 2
$ trap
$
```

The first line sets a trap on signal 2 (SIGINT).  The second line prints the current traps — you would have to capture the standard output from this and parse it for the signal you want.
Then, you can add your code to what was already there — noting that the prior code will most probably include an 'exit' operation.  The third invocation of trap clears the trap on 2/INT. The last one shows that there are no traps outstanding.

You can also use `trap -p INT` or `trap -p 2` to print the trap for a specific signal.

Answer (score 9):

I didn't like having to play with these string manipulations which are confusing at the best of times, so I came up with something like this:

(obviously you can modify it for other signals)

```
exit_trap_command=""
function cleanup {
    eval "$exit_trap_command"
}
trap cleanup EXIT

function add_exit_trap {
    local to_add=$1
    if [[ -z "$exit_trap_command" ]]
    then
        exit_trap_command="$to_add"
    else
        exit_trap_command="$exit_trap_command; $to_add"
    fi
}
```

Comment: Eventually: `exit_trap_command="${to_add:+$to_add${exit_trap_command:+;}}$exit_trap_command"`

Comment: Nice. You can initialize `exit_trap_command` to `:` to avoid append check!

Answer (score 6):

Here's another option:

```
on_exit_acc () {
    local next="$1"
    eval "on_exit () {
        local oldcmd='$(echo "$next" | sed -e s/\'/\'\\\\\'\'/g)'
        local newcmd=\"\$oldcmd; \$1\"
        trap -- \"\$newcmd\" 0
        on_exit_acc \"\$newcmd\"
    }"
}
on_exit_acc true
```

Usage:

```
$ on_exit date
$ on_exit 'echo "Goodbye from '\''`uname`'\''!"'
$ exit
exit
Sat Jan 18 18:31:49 PST 2014
Goodbye from 'FreeBSD'!
tap#
```

Answer (score 6):

I liked Richard Hansen's answer, but I don't care for embedded functions so an alternate is:

```
#===================================================================
# FUNCTION trap_add ()
#
# Purpose:  appends a command to a trap
#
# - 1st arg:  code to add
# - remaining args:  names of traps to modify
#
# Example:  trap_add 'echo "in trap DEBUG"' DEBUG
#
# See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338030/multiple-bash-traps-for-the-same-signal
#===================================================================
trap_add() {
    trap_add_cmd=$1; shift || fatal "${FUNCNAME} usage error"
    new_cmd=
    for trap_add_name in "$@"; do
        # Grab the currently defined trap commands for this trap
        existing_cmd=`trap -p "${trap_add_name}" |  awk -F"'" '{print $2}'`

        # Define default command
        [ -z "${existing_cmd}" ] && existing_cmd="echo exiting @ `date`"

        # Generate the new command
        new_cmd="${existing_cmd};${trap_add_cmd}"

        # Assign the test
         trap   "${new_cmd}" "${trap_add_name}" || \
                fatal "unable to add to trap ${trap_add_name}"
    done
}
```

Comment: This won't work if the existing trap action contains a single quote (e.g., `trap "echo 'foo'" EXIT`), which is why my answer uses an embedded function.

Answer (score 4):

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70217274/5447906) I implemented a simple solution. Here I implement another solution that is based on extracting of previous trap commands from `trap -p` output. But I don't know how much it is portable because I'm not sure that `trap -p` output is regulated. Maybe its format can be changed in future (but I doubt that).

```
trap_add()
{
    local new="$1"
    local sig="$2"

    # Get raw trap output.
    local old="$(trap -p "$sig")"

    # Extract previous commands from raw trap output.
    old="${old#*\'}"          # Remove first ' and everything before it.
    old="${old%\'*}"          # Remove last  ' and everything after  it.
    old="${old//\'\\\'\'/\'}" # Replace every '\'' (escaped ') to just '.

    # Combine new and old commands. Separate them by newline.
    trap -- "$new
$old" "$sig"
}

trap_add 'echo AAA'      EXIT
trap_add '{ echo BBB; }' EXIT
```

But this solution doesn't work well with subshells. Unfortunately `trap -p` prints commands of outer shell. And we execute them in subshell after extracting.

```
trap_add 'echo AAA' EXIT
( trap_add 'echo BBB' EXIT; )
```

In the above example `echo AAA` is executed twice: first time in subshell and second time in outer shell.

We have to check whether we are in new subshell and if we are then we must not take commands from `trap -p`.

```
trap_add()
{
    local new="$1"

    # Avoid inheriting trap commands from outer shell.
    if [[ "${trap_subshell:-}" != "$BASH_SUBSHELL" ]]; then
        # We are in new subshell, don't take commands from outer shell.
        trap_subshell="$BASH_SUBSHELL"
        local old=
    else
        # Get raw trap output.
        local old="$(trap -p EXIT)"

        # Extract previous commands from trap output.
        old="${old#*\'}"          # Remove first ' and everything before it.
        old="${old%\'*}"          # Remove last  ' and everything after  it.
        old="${old//\'\\\'\'/\'}" # Replace every '\'' (escaped ') to just '.
    fi

    # Combine new and old commands. Separate them by newline.
    trap -- "$new
$old" EXIT
}
```

Note that to avoid security issue you have to reset the `trap_subshell` variable at script startup.

```
trap_subshell=
```

Unfortunately the solution above works only with EXIT signal now. A generic solution that works with any signal is below.

```
# Check if argument is number.
is_num()
{
    [ -n "$1" ] && [ "$1" -eq "$1" ] 2>/dev/null
}

# Convert signal name to signal number.
to_sig_num()
{
    if is_num "$1"; then
      # Signal is already number.
      kill -l "$1" >/dev/null # Check that signal number is valid.
      echo    "$1"            # Return result.
    else
      # Convert to signal number.
      kill -l "$1"
    fi
}

trap_add()
{
    local new="$1"
    local sig="$2"

    local sig_num
    sig_num=$(to_sig_num "$sig")

    # Avoid inheriting trap commands from outer shell.
    if [[ "${trap_subshell[$sig_num]:-}" != "$BASH_SUBSHELL" ]]; then
        # We are in new subshell, don't take commands from outer shell.
        trap_subshell[$sig_num]="$BASH_SUBSHELL"
        local old=
    else
        # Get raw trap output.
        local old="$(trap -p "$sig")"

        # Extract previous commands from trap output.
        old="${old#*\'}"          # Remove first ' and everything before it.
        old="${old%\'*}"          # Remove last  ' and everything after  it.
        old="${old//\'\\\'\'/\'}" # Replace every '\'' (escaped ') to just '.
    fi

    # Combine new and old commands. Separate them by newline.
    trap -- "$new
$old" "$sig"
}

trap_subshell=

trap_add 'echo AAA'      EXIT
trap_add '{ echo BBB; }' 0 # The same as EXIT.
```

Answer (score 3):

I have been wrote a set of functions for myself to a bit resolve this task in a convenient way.

**Update**: The implementation here is obsoleted and left here as a demonstration. The new implementation is more complex, having dependencies, supports a wider range of cases and quite big to be placed here.

New implementation: https://sf.net/p/tacklelib/tacklelib/HEAD/tree/trunk/bash/tacklelib/traplib.sh

Here is the list of features of the new implementation:

**Pros**:

1. Automatically restores the previous trap handler in nested functions.
    Originally the `RETURN` trap restores ONLY if ALL functions in the stack did set it.
2. The `RETURN` signal trap can support other signal traps to achieve the RAII pattern as in other languages.
    For example, to temporary disable interruption handling and auto restore it at the end of a function
    while an initialization code is executing.
3. Protection from call not from a function context in case of the `RETURN` signal trap.
4. The not `RETURN` signal handlers in the whole stack invokes together in a bash process from the
    bottom to the top and executes them in order reversed to the `tkl_push_trap` function calls
5. The `RETURN` signal trap handlers invokes only for a single function from the bottom to the top in
    reverse order to the `tkl_push_trap` function calls.
6. Because the `EXIT` signal does not trigger the `RETURN` signal trap handler, then the `EXIT` signal trap
    handler does setup automatically at least once per bash process when the `RETURN` signal trap handler
    makes setup at first time in a bash process.
    That includes all bash processes, for example, represented as `(...)` or `$(...)` operators.
    So the `EXIT` signal trap handlers automatically handles all the `RETURN` trap handlers before to run itself.
7. The `RETURN` signal trap handler still can call to `tkl_push_trap` and `tkl_pop_trap` functions to process
    the not `RETURN` signal traps
8. The `RETURN` signal trap handler can call to `tkl_set_trap_postponed_exit` function from both the `EXIT` and
    `RETURN` signal trap handlers.
    If is called from the `RETURN` signal trap handler, then the `EXIT` trap handler will be called after all the
    `RETURN` signal trap handlers in the bash process.
    If is called from the `EXIT` signal trap handler, then the `EXIT` trap handler will change the exit code after
    the last `EXIT` signal trap handler is invoked.
9. Faster access to trap stack as a global variable instead of usage the `(...)` or `$(...)` operators
    which invokes an external bash process.
10. The `source` command ignores by the `RETURN` signal trap handler, so all calls to the `source` command will not
     invoke the `RETURN` signal trap user code (marked in the Pros, because `RETURN` signal trap handler has to be
     called only after return from a function in the first place and not from a script inclusion).

**Cons**:

1. You must not use builtin `trap` command in the handler passed to the `tkl_push_trap` function as `tkl_*_trap` functions
    does use it internally.
2. You must not use builtin `exit` command in the `EXIT` signal handlers while the `EXIT` signal trap
    handler is running. Otherwise that will leave the rest of the `RETURN` and `EXIT` signal trap handlers not executed.
    To change the exit code from the `EXIT` handler you can use `tkl_set_trap_postponed_exit` function for that.
3. You must not use builtin `return` command in the `RETURN` signal trap handler while the `RETURN` signal trap handler
    is running. Otherwise that will leave the rest of the `RETURN` and `EXIT` signal trap handlers not executed.
4. All calls to the `tkl_push_trap` and `tkl_pop_trap` functions has no effect if has been called from a trap
    handler for a signal the trap handler is handling (recursive call through the signal).
5. You have to replace all builtin `trap` commands in nested or 3dparty scripts by `tkl_*_trap` functions if
    already using the library.
6. The `source` command ignores by the `RETURN` signal trap handler, so all calls to the `source` command will not
    invoke the `RETURN` signal trap user code (marked in the Cons, because of losing the back compatability here).

**Old implementation**:

**traplib.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

# Script can be ONLY included by "source" command.
if [[ -n "$BASH" && (-z "$BASH_LINENO" || ${BASH_LINENO[0]} -gt 0) ]] && (( ! ${#SOURCE_TRAPLIB_SH} )); then 

SOURCE_TRAPLIB_SH=1 # including guard

function GetTrapCmdLine()
{
  local IFS=$' \t\r\n'
  GetTrapCmdLineImpl RETURN_VALUES "$@"
}

function GetTrapCmdLineImpl()
{
  local out_var="$1"
  shift

  # drop return values
  eval "$out_var=()"

  local IFS
  local trap_sig
  local stack_var
  local stack_arr
  local trap_cmdline
  local trap_prev_cmdline
  local i

  i=0
  IFS=$' \t\r\n'; for trap_sig in "$@"; do
    stack_var="_traplib_stack_${trap_sig}_cmdline"
    declare -a "stack_arr=(\"\${$stack_var[@]}\")"
    if (( ${#stack_arr[@]} )); then
      for trap_cmdline in "${stack_arr[@]}"; do
        declare -a "trap_prev_cmdline=(\"\${$out_var[i]}\")"
        if [[ -n "$trap_prev_cmdline" ]]; then
          eval "$out_var[i]=\"\$trap_cmdline; \$trap_prev_cmdline\"" # the last srored is the first executed
        else
          eval "$out_var[i]=\"\$trap_cmdline\""
        fi
      done
    else
      # use the signal current trap command line
      declare -a "trap_cmdline=(`trap -p "$trap_sig"`)"
      eval "$out_var[i]=\"\${trap_cmdline[2]}\""
    fi
    (( i++ ))
  done
}

function PushTrap()
{
  # drop return values
  EXIT_CODES=()
  RETURN_VALUES=()

  local cmdline="$1"
  [[ -z "$cmdline" ]] && return 0 # nothing to push
  shift

  local IFS

  local trap_sig
  local stack_var
  local stack_arr
  local trap_cmdline_size
  local prev_cmdline

  IFS=$' \t\r\n'; for trap_sig in "$@"; do
    stack_var="_traplib_stack_${trap_sig}_cmdline"
    declare -a "stack_arr=(\"\${$stack_var[@]}\")"
    trap_cmdline_size=${#stack_arr[@]}
    if (( trap_cmdline_size )); then
      # append to the end is equal to push trap onto stack
      eval "$stack_var[trap_cmdline_size]=\"\$cmdline\""
    else
      # first stack element is always the trap current command line if not empty
      declare -a "prev_cmdline=(`trap -p $trap_sig`)"
      if (( ${#prev_cmdline[2]} )); then
        eval "$stack_var=(\"\${prev_cmdline[2]}\" \"\$cmdline\")"
      else
        eval "$stack_var=(\"\$cmdline\")"
      fi
    fi
    # update the signal trap command line
    GetTrapCmdLine "$trap_sig"
    trap "${RETURN_VALUES[0]}" "$trap_sig"
    EXIT_CODES[i++]=$?
  done
}

function PopTrap()
{
  # drop return values
  EXIT_CODES=()
  RETURN_VALUES=()

  local IFS

  local trap_sig
  local stack_var
  local stack_arr
  local trap_cmdline_size
  local trap_cmd_line
  local i

  i=0
  IFS=$' \t\r\n'; for trap_sig in "$@"; do
    stack_var="_traplib_stack_${trap_sig}_cmdline"
    declare -a "stack_arr=(\"\${$stack_var[@]}\")"
    trap_cmdline_size=${#stack_arr[@]}
    if (( trap_cmdline_size )); then
      (( trap_cmdline_size-- ))
      RETURN_VALUES[i]="${stack_arr[trap_cmdline_size]}"
      # unset the end
      unset $stack_var[trap_cmdline_size]
      (( !trap_cmdline_size )) && unset $stack_var

      # update the signal trap command line
      if (( trap_cmdline_size )); then
        GetTrapCmdLineImpl trap_cmd_line "$trap_sig"
        trap "${trap_cmd_line[0]}" "$trap_sig"
      else
        trap "" "$trap_sig" # just clear the trap
      fi
      EXIT_CODES[i]=$?
    else
      # nothing to pop
      RETURN_VALUES[i]=""
    fi
    (( i++ ))
  done
}

function PopExecTrap()
{
  # drop exit codes
  EXIT_CODES=()

  local IFS=$' \t\r\n'

  PopTrap "$@"

  local cmdline
  local i

  i=0
  IFS=$' \t\r\n'; for cmdline in "${RETURN_VALUES[@]}"; do
    # execute as function and store exit code
    eval "function _traplib_immediate_handler() { $cmdline; }"
    _traplib_immediate_handler
    EXIT_CODES[i++]=$?
    unset _traplib_immediate_handler
  done
}

fi
```

**test.sh**

```
#/bin/bash

source ./traplib.sh

function Exit()
{
  echo exitting...
  exit $@
}

pushd ".." && {
  PushTrap "echo popd; popd" EXIT
  echo 111 || Exit
  PopExecTrap EXIT
}

GetTrapCmdLine EXIT
echo -${RETURN_VALUES[@]}-

pushd ".." && {
  PushTrap "echo popd; popd" EXIT
  echo 222 && Exit
  PopExecTrap EXIT
}
```

**Usage**

```
cd ~/test
./test.sh
```

**Output**

```
~ ~/test
111
popd
~/test
--
~ ~/test
222
exitting...
popd
~/test
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to have multiple handlers for the same trap, but the same handler can do multiple things.

The one thing I don't like in the various other answers doing the same thing is the use of string manipulation to get at the current trap function. There are two easy ways of doing this: arrays and arguments. Arguments is the most reliable one, but I'll show arrays first.

#### Arrays

When using arrays, you rely on the fact that `trap -p SIGNAL` returns `trap -- ??? SIGNAL`, so whatever is the value of `???`, there are three more words in the array.

Therefore you can do this:

```
declare -a trapDecl
trapDecl=($(trap -p SIGNAL))
currentHandler="${trapDecl[@]:2:${#trapDecl[@]} - 3}"
eval "trap -- 'your handler;'${currentHandler} SIGNAL"
```

So let's explain this. First, variable `trapDecl` is declared as an array. If you do this inside a function, it will also be local, which is convenient.

Next we assign the output of `trap -p SIGNAL` to the array. To give an example, let's say you are running this after having sourced osht (unit testing for shell), and that the signal is `EXIT`. The output of `trap -p EXIT` will be `trap -- '_osht_cleanup' EXIT`, so the `trapDecl` assignment will be substituted like this:

```
trapDecl=(trap -- '_osht_cleanup' EXIT)
```

The parenthesis there are normal array assignment, so `trapDecl` becomes an array with four elements: `trap`, `--`, `'_osht_cleanup'` and `EXIT`.

Next we extract the current handler -- that could be inlined in the next line, but for explanation's sake I assigned it to a variable first. Simplifying that line, I'm doing this: `currentHandler="${array[@]:offset:length}"`, which is the syntax used by Bash to say pick `length` elements starting at element `offset`. Since it starts counting from `0`, number `2` will be `'_osht_cleanup'`. Next, `${#trapDecl[@]}` is the number of elements inside `trapDecl`, which will be 4 in the example. You subtract 3 because there are three elements you don't want: `trap`, `--` and `EXIT`. I don't need to use `$(...)` around that expression because arithmetic expansion is already performed on the `offset` and `length` arguments.

The final line performs an `eval`, which is used so that the shell will interpret the quoting from the output of `trap`. If we do parameter substitution on that line, it expands to the following in the example:

```
eval "trap -- 'your handler;''_osht_cleanup' EXIT"
```

Do not be confused by the double quote in the middle (`''`). Bash simply concatenates two quotes strings if they are next to each other. For example, `'1'"2"'3''4'` is expanded to `1234` by Bash. Or, to give a more interesting example, `1" "2` is the same thing as `"1 2"`. So eval takes that string and evaluates it, which is equivalent to executing this:

```
trap -- 'your handler;''_osht_cleanup' EXIT
```

And that will handle the quoting correctly, turning everything between `--` and `EXIT` into a single parameter.

To give a more complex example, I'm prepending a directory clean up to the osht handler, so my `EXIT` signal now has this:

```
trap -- 'rm -fr '\''/var/folders/7d/qthcbjz950775d6vn927lxwh0000gn/T/tmp.CmOubiwq'\'';_osht_cleanup' EXIT
```

If you assign that to `trapDecl`, it will have size 6 because of the spaces on the handler. That is, `'rm` is one element, and so is `-fr`, instead of `'rm -fr ...'` being a single element.

But `currentHandler` will get all three elements (6 - 3 = 3), and the quoting will work out when `eval` is run.

#### Arguments

Arguments just skips all the array handling part and uses `eval` up front to get the quoting right. The downside is that you replace the positional arguments on bash, so this is best done from a function. This is the code, though:

```
eval "set -- $(trap -p SIGNAL)"
trap -- "your handler${3:+;}${3}" SIGNAL
```

The first line will set the positional arguments to the output of `trap -p SIGNAL`. Using the example from the Arrays section, `$1` will be `trap`, `$2` will be `--`, `$3` will be `_osht_cleanup` (no quotes!), and `$4` will be `EXIT`.

The next line is pretty straightforward, except for `${3:+;}`. The `${X:+Y}` syntax means *"output `Y` if the variable `X` is unset or null"*. So it expands to `;` if `$3` is set, or nothing otherwise (if there was no previous handler for `SIGNAL`).

Answer (score 2):

## Simple ways to do it

1. If all the signal handling functions are known at the same time, then the following is sufficient (has said by [Jonathan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338030/multiple-bash-traps-for-the-same-signal#answer-3338171)):

   ```sh
   trap 'handler1;handler2;handler3' EXIT
   ```
2. Else, if there is an existing handler(s) that should stay, then new handlers can easily be added like this:

   ```sh
   trap "$( trap -p EXIT | cut -f2 -d \' );newHandler" EXIT
   ```
3. If you don't know if there are existing handlers but want to keep them in this case, do the following:

```sh
 handlers="$( trap -p EXIT | cut -f2 -d \' )"
 trap "${handlers}${handlers:+;}newHandler" EXIT
```

4. It can be factorized in a function like that:

```sh
trap-add() {
    local sig="${2:?Signal required}"
    hdls="$( trap -p ${sig} | cut -f2 -d \' )";
    trap "${hdls}${hdls:+;}${1:?Handler required}" "${sig}"
}

export -f trap-add
```

Usage:

```sh
trap-add 'echo "Bye bye"' EXIT
trap-add 'echo "See you next time"' EXIT
```

**Remark** : This works only as long as the handlers are function names, or simple instructions that did not contain any simple code (simple code conflicts with `cut -f2 -d \'`).

Comment: Additional limitation: If `trap-add` is used in a subshell, the handlers will incorrectly be inherited by the subshell, causing the exit traps meant for the parent shell to be executed twice – when exiting the subshell and when exiting the parent shell. E.g. `onExit () { trap-add "echo -n .$1" exit; }; echo -n .start; onExit 'outer'; ( onExit 'inner' ); echo -n .end` yields output `.start.outer.inner.end.outer`. Reason being, that `trap -p EXIT` (incorrectly?) reports the parent shell's trap, even though it isn't inherited by the subshell.

Answer (score 1):

I add a slightly more robust version of [Laurent Simon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58689419/2075630)'s `trap-add` script:

- Allows using arbitrary commands as trap, including such with `'` characters
- Works only in bash; It could be rewritten with `sed` instead of bash pattern substitution, but that would make it significantly slower.
- Still suffers from causing unwanted inheritance of the traps in subshells.

```
trap-add () {
    local handler=$(trap -p "$2")
    handler=${handler/trap -- \'/}    # /- Strip `trap '...' SIGNAL` -> ...
    handler=${handler%\'*}            # \-
    handler=${handler//\'\\\'\'/\'}   # <- Unquote quoted quotes ('\'')
    trap "${handler} $1;" "$2"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would like to propose my solution of multiple trap functions for simple scripts

```
# Executes cleanup functions on exit
function on_exit {
    for FUNCTION in $(declare -F); do
        if [[ ${FUNCTION} == *"_on_exit" ]]; then
            >&2 echo ${FUNCTION}
            eval ${FUNCTION}
        fi
    done
}
trap on_exit EXIT

function remove_fifo_on_exit {
    >&2 echo Removing FIFO...
}

function stop_daemon_on_exit {
    >&2 echo Stopping daemon...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just like to add my simple version as an example.

```
trap -- 'echo "Version 1";' EXIT;

function add_to_trap {
    local -a TRAP;
    # this will put parts of trap command into TRAP array
    eval "TRAP=($(trap -p EXIT))";
    # 3rd field is trap command. Concat strings.
    trap -- 'echo "Version 2"; '"${TRAP[2]}" EXIT;
}

add_to_trap;
```

If this code is run, will print:

```
Version 2
Version 1
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple and compact solution to run multiple `trap`'s by executing all functions that start with the name `trap_`:

```
trap 'eval $(declare -F | grep -oP "trap_[^ ]+" | tr "\n" ";")' EXIT
```

Now simply add as many trap functions as you like::

```
# write stdout and stderr to a log file
exec &> >(tee -a "/var/log/scripts/${0//\//_}.log")
trap_shrink_logs() { echo "$(tail -n 1000 "/var/log/scripts/${0//\//_}.log")" > "/var/log/scripts/${0//\//_}.log" }

# make script race condition safe
[[ -d "/tmp/${0//\//_}" ]] || ! mkdir "/tmp/${0//\//_}" && echo "Already running!" && exit 1
trap_remove_lock() { rmdir "/tmp/${0//\//_}"; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I usually do it. It's not much different from what other people have suggested here but my version seems dramatically simpler and so far it always worked as desired for me.

Somewhere in the code, set a trap:

```
trap "echo Hello" EXIT
```

and later on update it:

```
oldTrap=$(trap -p EXIT)
oldTrap=${oldTrap#"trap -- '"}
oldTrap=${oldTrap%"' EXIT"}; 
trap "$oldTrap; echo World" EXIT
```

finally, on exit

```
Hello
World
```

Answer (score 0):

A special case of [Richard Hansen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7287873/52499) (great idea). I usually need it for EXIT traps. In such case:

```sh
extract_trap_cmd() { printf '%s\n' "${3-}"; }
get_exit_trap_cmd() {
    eval "extract_trap_cmd $(trap -p EXIT)"
}

...
trap "echo '1  2'; $(get_exit_trap_cmd)" EXIT
...
trap "echo '3  4'; $(get_exit_trap_cmd)" EXIT
```

Or this way, if you will:

```sh
add_exit_trap_handler() {
    trap "$1; $(get_exit_trap_cmd)" EXIT
}
...
add_exit_trap_handler "echo '5  6'"
...
add_exit_trap_handler "echo '7  8'"
```

Answer (score 0):

Always assuming I remember to pass multiple code snippets in semi-colon delimited fashion (as per bash(1)s' requirement for multiple commands on a single line, it's rare that the following (or something similar to it) fails to fulfil my meagre requirements...

```
extend-trap() {
    local sig=${1:?'Der, you forgot the sig!!!!'}
    shift
    
    local code s ; while IFS=\' read code s ; do
        code="$code ; $*"
    done < <(trap -p $sig)

    trap "$code" $sig
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### I'd like something simpler... :)

My humble contrib:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# global vars
TRAPS=()

# functions
function add_exit_trap() {     TRAPS+=("$@")     }

function execute_exit_traps() {
   local I
   local POSITIONS=${!TRAPS[@]}  # retorna os índices válidos do array
   for I in $POSITIONS
   do
        echo "executing TRAPS[$I]=${TRAPS[I]}"
        eval ${TRAPS[I]}
   done
}

#    M A I N

LOCKFILE="/tmp/lock.me.1234567890"
touch $LOCKFILE

trap execute_exit_traps EXIT

add_exit_trap "rm -f $LOCKFILE && echo lock removed."
add_exit_trap "ls -l $LOCKFILE"
add_exit_trap "echo END"

echo "showing lockfile..."
ls -l $LOCKFILE
```

`add_exit_trap()` keeps adding strings (commands) to a bash global array while
`execute_exit_traps()` just loops thru that array and eval the commands

Executed script...

```sh
showing lockfile...
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 Mar 24 10:08 /tmp/lock.me.1234567890
executing TRAPS[0]=rm -f /tmp/lock.me.1234567890 && echo lock removed.
lock removed.
executing TRAPS[1]=ls -l /tmp/lock.me.1234567890
ls: cannot access /tmp/lock.me.1234567890: No such file or directory
executing TRAPS[2]=echo END
END
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to save commands for trap to variable and, when adding new trap, to restore them from that variable.

```
trap_add()
{
    # Combine new and old commands. Separate them by newline.
    trap_cmds="$1
$trap_cmds"
    trap -- "$trap_cmds" EXIT
}

trap_add 'echo AAA'
trap_add '{ echo BBB; }'
```

Unfortunately this solution does not work well with subshells, because subshell inherits outer shell variables and thus outer shell trap commands are executed in subshell.

```
trap_add 'echo AAA'
( trap_add 'echo BBB'; )
```

In the above example `echo AAA` is executed twice: first time in subshell and second time in outer shell.

We have to check whether we are in new subshell and if we are then we must not take commands from the `trap_cmds` variable.

```
trap_add()
{
    # Avoid inheriting trap commands from outer shell.
    if [[ "${trap_subshell:-}" != "$BASH_SUBSHELL" ]]; then
        # We are in new subshell, don't take commands from outer shell.
        trap_subshell="$BASH_SUBSHELL"
        trap_cmds=
    fi

    # Combine new and old commands. Separate them by newline.
    trap_cmds="$1
$trap_cmds"
    trap -- "$trap_cmds" EXIT
}
```

Note that to avoid security issue you have to reset the used variables at script startup.

```
trap_subshell=
trap_cmds=
```

Otherwise someone who runs your script can inject their malicious commands via environment variables.

```
export trap_subshell=0
export trap_cmds='echo "I hacked you"'
./your_script
```

Generic version that works with arbitrary signals is below.

```
# Check if argument is number.
is_num()
{
    [ -n "$1" ] && [ "$1" -eq "$1" ] 2>/dev/null
}

# Convert signal name to signal number.
to_sig_num()
{
    if is_num "$1"; then
      # Signal is already number.
      kill -l "$1" >/dev/null # Check that signal number is valid.
      echo    "$1"            # Return result.
    else
      # Convert to signal number.
      kill -l "$1"
    fi
}

trap_add()
{
    local cmd sig sig_num

    cmd="$1"
    sig="$2"
    sig_num=$(to_sig_num "$sig")

    # Avoid inheriting trap commands from outer shell.
    if [[ "${trap_subshell[$sig_num]:-}" != "$BASH_SUBSHELL" ]]; then
        # We are in new subshell, don't take commands from outer shell.
        trap_subshell[$sig_num]="$BASH_SUBSHELL"
        trap_cmds[$sig_num]=
    fi

    # Combine new and old commands. Separate them by newline.
    trap_cmds[$sig_num]="$cmd
${trap_cmds[$sig_num]}"

    trap -- "${trap_cmds[$sig_num]}" $sig
}

trap_subshell=
trap_cmds=

trap_add 'echo AAA'      EXIT
trap_add '{ echo BBB; }' 0 # The same as EXIT.
```

**PS** In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70218374/5447906) I implemented another solution that gets previous commands from `trap -p` output.

Answer (score 0):

There's two actually correct answers.

Answer #1: Create a subshell.

```bash
## some code that may contain other traps

(
  trap 'whatever' EXIT HUP INT ABRT TERM
  somecommand
) # 'whatever' executed when leaving the subshell.
# Previous trap(s) restored.
```

Do [note the documentation](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_28) about traps inheritance:

> *Signals that were ignored on entry to a non-interactive shell cannot be trapped or reset*, although no error need be reported when attempting to do so.

Answer #2: Save and restore traps.

When the `trap` command is invoked without arguments, it will print entire list of traps formatted for shell re-evaluation. Thus, if subshell is not an option, something like this could be done:

```bash
save_traps=$(trap)
trap 'something' HUP INT ABRT TERM
somecommand
eval "$save_traps"
```

But the root cause of the OP is most likely an XY problem. Suppose you have various commands called in different modules of your script and producing residue temp files across filesystem. Being a good citizen, you want to cleanup after yourself. And you employ `trap` to call cleanup tack. Instead of trying to stack traps, stack your cleanup list:

```bash
_cleanup_list=
_cleanup() {
    case "$1" in
        add) 
            shift
            for file; do _cleanup_list="${_cleanup_list:+$_cleanup_list }'$file'"; done
            ;;
        clear)
            for file in $_cleanup_list; do eval "[ -f $file ] && rm $file"; done
            ;;
    esac
}

trap '_cleanup clear' EXIT
```

Answer (score 0):

[Richard Hansen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7287873) is definitely the best, but in case you don't want to use an embedded function, here's an alternative:

```
function foo
{
    trap "echo outer" EXIT
    echo "in foo: $(trap -p EXIT)"
    bar
    echo "post bar: $(trap -p EXIT)"
}

function bar
{
    # this line is the money shot:
    trap "echo inner ; $(eval "( set -- $(trap -p EXIT) ; echo \$3 )")" EXIT
    echo "in bar: $(trap -p EXIT)"
}

( foo )
```

which produces this output:

```
in foo: trap -- 'echo outer' EXIT
in bar: trap -- 'echo inner ; echo outer' EXIT
post bar: trap -- 'echo inner ; echo outer' EXIT
inner
outer
```

Generalization to a reusable function left as an exercise for the reader.

Reasons you might not want to use an embedded function:

- I suppose it's slightly inefficient, as the function is defined every time its containing function executes.  I suspect, however, that this inefficiency is so negligible as to be irrelevant.
- More importantly, embedded functions are not localized to the containing function.  That means that you're polluting your caller's namespace, and maybe even overwriting one of *their* functions.  That seems like a Bad Idea™.

Answer (score 0):

Using bash arrays, we can avoid calls to `eval`, and still handle newlines correctly. It is also simpler, since it avoids having to create multiple functions in order to interpret the result of 'trap -p' correctly. This does mean that your shell must support arrays. You can refer to "[Test for array support by shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/238080/test-for-array-support-by-shell)" to take appropriate action.

```
trap_add() {
  declare -a "current_trap=($(trap -p "$2"))"
  # shellcheck disable=SC2064
  trap "$(printf '%s\n' "${current_trap[2]:-}")$1;" "$2"
}

trap_add 'printf "in EXIT\n"'$'\n''printf "in EXIT 2\n"' EXIT
trap_add 'printf "in EXIT 3\n"' EXIT

trap -p EXIT
```

Note that the way I've set up the printf statement causes this to be a FIFO, so change the order if you need it to be FILO. It should also be trivial to add an argument to control this, or add a separate function to prepend the new trap code.

The result of the above is:

```
$ ./trap
trap -- 'printf "in EXIT\n"
printf "in EXIT 2\n";printf "in EXIT 3\n";' EXIT
in EXIT
in EXIT 2
in EXIT 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I do this:

```
  trap-push() {
    local handler="$1"
    shift
    for signal in "$@"
    do
      # let eval parse trap -p
      eval "set -- $(trap -p ${signal})"

      # unfortunately, trap -p prints outer-level traps; protect each handler to run at proper level
      trap -- "status=\${status:-\$?}; ((BASH_SUBSHELL==$BASH_SUBSHELL)) && { ${handler}; } ||: ${3:+$'\n'}${3:-}" ${signal}
    done
  }

  trap-pop() {
    local result=""
    for signal in "$@"
    do
      # let eval parse trap -p
      eval "set -- $(trap -p ${signal})"

      local existing="${3:-}"
      local removed="${existing%%$'\n'*}" # first
      local retained="${existing#*$'\n'}" # rest

      if [[ ${retained} ]]
      then trap -- "${retained}" ${signal}
      else trap - ${signal} # reset default action
      fi

      result+="${removed};"
    done
    echo "${result}"
  }

  trap-pop-exec() {
    # run popped trap handler
    eval "$(trap-pop "$@")"
  }
```