# Writing try catch finally in shell

Tags: shell, syntax, try-catch, finally

Is there a linux bash command like the java try catch finally?
Or does the linux shell always go on?

```
try {
   `executeCommandWhichCanFail`
   mv output
} catch {
    mv log
} finally {
    rm tmp
}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7251619/how-can-i-try-to-do-something-and-then-detect-if-it-fails-in-bash

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6961389/exception-handling-in-shell-scripting

Comment: @KugathasanAbimaran Had to use the keyword error-handling instead of try catch finally, thanks for the link!

Comment: Related: [Raise error in a Bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50265513/6862601)

Answer (score 117, accepted):

Well, sort of:

```bsh
{ # your 'try' block
    executeCommandWhichCanFail &&
    mv output
} || { # your 'catch' block
    mv log
}

 rm tmp # finally: this will always happen
```

Comment: Note you have to use the `&&` after the `executeCommandWhichCanFail` otherwise it proceeds blindly.  Even if you precede it with use `set -e` (which I don't understand).

Comment: Short and concise. But I'd prefer using `trap`, as `||` doesn't ensure the other part gets executed even under exceptional conditions (signals), which is pretty much what one expects from `finally`.

Comment: You could probably use `(...)` instead of `{...}` and then you wouldn't have to use && on every line

Comment: @AJP This weird behaviour is at least documented: "If a compound command or shell function executes in a context where -e is being ignored, none of the commands executed within the compound command or function body will be affected by the -e setting, [...]" https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#The-Set-Builtin  This even applies to `( )` subshell groups, despite the fact that `-e` ordinarily propagates to subshells.

Answer (score 173):

Based on your example, it looks like you are trying to do something akin to always deleting a temporary file, regardless of how a script exits. In Bash to do this try the `trap` builtin command to trap the `EXIT` signal.

```
#!/bin/bash

trap 'rm tmp' EXIT

if executeCommandWhichCanFail; then
    mv output
else
    mv log
    exit 1 #Exit with failure
fi

exit 0 #Exit with success
```

The `rm tmp` statement in the `trap` is always executed when the script exits, so the file "tmp" will always tried to be deleted.

Installed traps can also be reset; a call to trap with only a signal name will reset the signal handler.

```
trap EXIT
```

For more details, see the bash manual page: `man bash`

Comment: One nice thing about using 'trap' is that you can also catch other signals besides EXIT.  In particular, you can catch SIGINT (Control-C).  To do so, just tack it on the end of the trap statement.  For example `trap 'rm tmp' EXIT SIGINT`.

Comment: yep,SIGTERM would also be helpful. make the script robust.[clean up tmp files even if 'been killed']

Comment: From a quick test it seems that the `EXIT` handler is **also** called for `SIGINT` and `SIGTERM`

Comment: This is for sure the cleanest way to do it.

Comment: Good answer; it may be worth pointing out that execution of the trap doesn't affect the exit status of the script - that's an advantage over `if/else` or `||` approaches, and more like C++ or Java `try`/`catch`.

Comment: To expand on the above comments: in my testing, Control-C causes SIGINT to fire first, followed by EXIT.  Therefore, for the purpose being discussed here, it's redundant to trap SIGINT, and in fact trapping both causes your cleanup command to be executed twice -- very likely not what you want.

Trapping SIGTERM on the other hand caused the program to NOT terminate when it received a kill.  A kill -9 skips all three traps.  So trapping SIGTERM is not recommended in this case either.  (If you do decide to trap SIGTERM for some reason, you probably want to call 'exit' in your trap handler.)

Comment: Using `trap ... EXIT` seems to be the closest way to mimic the `finally { ... }` block. But do note that the `EXIT` trap command is executed **at the end** of the script, right before it exits. Consider if there are some codes (e.g. echo 'blah') after the `finally { ... }` block, the command(s) in the `finally` block will still be executed **before** those codes (i.e. before echo 'blah'). However, the `EXIT` trap command(s) always be executed at the end.

Answer (score 2):

I found success in my script with this syntax:

```
# Try, catch, finally
(echo "try this") && (echo "and this") || echo "this is the catch statement!"

# this is the 'finally' statement
echo "finally this"
```

If either try statement throws an error or ends with `exit 1`, then the interpreter moves on to the catch statement and then the finally statement.

If both try statements succeed (and/or end with `exit`), the interpreter will skip the catch statement and then run the finally statement.

Example_1:

```
goodFunction1(){
  # this function works great
  echo "success1"
}

goodFunction2(){
  # this function works great
  echo "success2"
  exit
}

(goodFunction1) && (goodFunction2) || echo "Oops, that didn't work!"

echo "Now this happens!"
```

Output_1

```
success1
success2
Now this happens!
```

Example _2

```
functionThrowsErr(){
  # this function returns an error
  ech "halp meh"
}

goodFunction2(){
  # this function works great
  echo "success2"
  exit
}

(functionThrowsErr) && (goodFunction2) || echo "Oops, that didn't work!"

echo "Now this happens!"
```

Output_2

```
main.sh: line 3: ech: command not found
Oops, that didn't work!
Now this happens!
```

Example_3

```
functionThrowsErr(){
  # this function returns an error
  echo "halp meh"
  exit 1
}

goodFunction2(){
  # this function works great
  echo "success2"
}

(functionThrowsErr) && (goodFunction2) || echo "Oops, that didn't work!"

echo "Now this happens!"
```

Output_3

```
halp meh
Oops, that didn't work!
Now this happens!
```

Note that the order of the functions will affect output. If you need both statements to be tried and caught separately, use two try catch statements.

```
(functionThrowsErr) || echo "Oops, functionThrowsErr didn't work!"
(goodFunction2) || echo "Oops, good function is bad"

echo "Now this happens!"
```

Output

```
halp meh
Oops, functionThrowsErr didn't work!
success2
Now this happens!
```

Comment: and what if one of these "try statements" raise error (throw exception) ? how does it handle errors (exceptions) ?

Comment: if one of the try statements exits from returning an error, or because there is a "exit 1" command, the interpreter will move on to the "catch", followed by the finally statement.

however, if a try statement exit with an "exit" command or by simply completing successfully, then the interpreter will move on to the finally statement without running the catch statement.

Comment: I updated my answer with examples that show how errors are handled in various scenarios depending what your program flow requires.

Answer (score 1):

`mv` takes two parameters, so may be you really wanted to cat the output file's contents:

```
echo `{ execCommand && cat output ; } || cat log`
rm -f tmp
```

Answer (score -1):

Another way to do it would be:

```
set -e;  # stop on errors

mkdir -p "$HOME/tmp/whatevs"

exit_code=0

(
  set +e;
  (
    set -e;
    echo 'foo'
    echo 'bar'
    echo 'biz'
  )
  exit_code="$?"
)

rm -rf "$HOME/tmp/whatevs"

if [[ "exit_code" != '0' ]]; then
   echo 'failed';
fi
```

although the above doesn't really offer any benefit over:

```
set -e;  # stop on errors

mkdir -p "$HOME/tmp/whatevs"

exit_code=0

(
    set -e;
    echo 'foo'
    echo 'bar'
    echo 'biz'
    exit 44;
    exit 43;

) || {
   exit_code="$?"  # exit code of last command which is 44
}

rm -rf "$HOME/tmp/whatevs"

if [[ "exit_code" != '0' ]]; then
   echo 'failed';
fi
```

Answer (score -1):

**Warning: exit traps are not *always* excuted.** Since writing this answer I have run into situations, where my exit trap would not be executed, causing loss of files, the reason of which I haven't found yet.

The issue occurred when I stopped a python script with `Ctrl+C`, which in turn had executed a bash script using exit traps -- which actually should cause the exit traps to be executed, since exit traps are executed on `SIGINT` in bash.

So, while `trap .. exit` is useful for cleanup, there are stil scenarios where it won't be executed, the most obvious ones being power outages and receiving `SIGKILL`.

---

I often end up with bash scripts becoming quite large, as I add additional options, or otherwise change them. When a bash-script contains a lot of functions, using 'trap EXIT' may become non-trivial.

For instance, consider a script invoked as

```
dotask TASK [ARG ...]
```

where each `TASK` may consists of substeps, where it is desirable to perform cleanup in between.

In this case, it is helpful to work with subshells to produce scoped exit traps, e.g.

```
function subTask (
    local tempFile=$(mktemp)
    trap "rm '${tempFile}'" exit
    ...
)
```

However, working with subshells can be tricky, as they can't set global variables of the parent shell.

Additionally, it is often inconvenient to write a single exit trap. For instance, the cleanup steps may depend on how far a function came before encountering an error. It would be nice to be able to make RAII style cleanup declarations:

```
function subTask (
    ...
    onExit 'rm tmp.1'
    ...
    onExit 'rm tmp.2'
    ...
)
```

It would seem obvious to use something like

```
handlers=""
function onExit { handlers+="$1;"; trap "$handlers" exit; }
```

to update the trap. But this fails for nested subshells, as it would cause premature execution of the parent shell's handlers. The client code would have to explicitly reset the `handlers` variable at the beginning of the subshell.

Solutions discussed in [[multiple bash traps for the same signal]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58689419/2075630), which patch the trap by using the output from `trap -p EXIT` will equally fail: Even though subshells don't inherit the `EXIT` trap, `trap -p exit` will display the parent shell's handler so, again, manual resetting is needed.