# Command for dropping the database if it exists and create new one in OrientDB

Tags: orientdb

I want to write a script which will be run on OrientDB Console. The script needs to delete the database if it exists and create new one.

I am using following commands:

```
drop database remote:localhost/testgraphdb1 root xyz

create database remote:localhost/testgraphdb1 root xyz local graph;
```

How can I avoid the error occurred when the command tries to drop a database which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had put this question on the OrientDB forum also. This feature (drop database if exists) doesn't exist. A new feature request will be created for this and hopefully this will be implemented soon.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/orient-database/nvW6vZmUk6k

Comment: Here is the feature request: [#2038](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/2038)

Comment: Look at TimH's solution below for the simple workaround.

Answer (score 4):

I use the same "console.sh myscript.sql" execution process and ran into the same issue. My search led me here and I followed up on the issues created for OrientDB. They are not addressed as of this writing. My solution was to do wrap the drop statement in the myscript.sql file as such:

```
set ignoreErrors true;
drop database remote:localhost/testgraphdb1 root xyz;
set ignoreErrors false;

create database remote:localhost/testgraphdb1 root xyz local graph;
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe use a `try/catch` block?

```
try{
    drop database remote:localhost/testgraphdb1 root xyz
}catch(e){
// Print ?
}
create database remote:localhost/testgraphdb1 root xyz local graph;
```

Comment: I don't know which language you use, depending on the language the catch could be like that: `catch(Exception e)`

Comment: It gives following error:                                           OrientDB console v.1.6.4 (build UNKNOWN@r; 2014-01-16 00:01:20+0100) www.orientechnologies.com
Type 'help' to display all the commands supported.
Installing extensions for GREMLIN language v.2.5.0-SNAPSHOT

!Unrecognized command: 'try{'

Comment: What's your language? `GREMLIN`?

Comment: I am writing a Script which will run on OrientDB console.sh

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15656492/linux-shell-try-catch-finally Maybe this.

Comment: I execute "console.sh myscript.sql" . It opens OrientDB console shell and then shell commands are fired. So unix commands can't be executed on OrientDB shell.